# KeyCloak - Create Realms/Users/Groups Programmatically?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, keycloak, keycloak-services

We've decided to move to [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org) for our identity and access management solution, rather than implement it entirely within our Java EE web app.  We're creating a multi-tenant solution, and would prefer to create security realms/users/groups programmatically through our workflow, rather than leveraging KeyCloak's self-registration functionality or web UI so that we can do things like grab credit card details for payment, etc.  I know that we could likely leverage the [admin REST APIs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.0/rest-api/index.html) to accomplish this, but I wasn't sure if there was a simpler way to do it besides hand-coding REST calls.  Does KeyCloak provide an admin client library that we could use?  Or are we stuck implementing a REST client for the admin APIs ourselves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found some info around the [KeyCloak Java Admin Client](https://www.n-k.de/2016/08/keycloak-admin-client.html).  [This gist](https://gist.github.com/sdnakhla/c3e5597ca005bd7a2ac23ec51309a0ce) has lots of useful examples showing how to managed users, realms, etc.

Comment: Did you find any documentation about that API?

Comment: FYI the gist url is now broken

Comment: There's another [gist](https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/c4e739c5a319cf78a4cff3b87173a84b) I found while searching the same topic

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Keycloak Java admin REST api client :

1. Add dependency to your project :

   - Maven

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
       <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
       <version>15.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   - Gradle

   ```
   implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:15.0.2'
   ```
2. Create instance of [`Keycloak`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/latest/index.html) using [`KeycloakBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/latest/index.html) using Password authentication for your admin user and default `admin-cli` client:

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://localhost:8081/auth")
            .realm("master")
            .clientId("admin-cli")
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .build();
```

3. To create new realm use [`RealmRepresentation`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.keycloak/keycloak-core/latest/org/keycloak/representations/idm/RealmRepresentation.html):

```
RealmRepresentation rr = new RealmRepresentation();
rr.setId("test-realm");
rr.setRealm("test-realm");
rr.setEnabled(true);

keycloak.realms().create(rr);
```

4. To create new user use [`UserRepresentation`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.keycloak/keycloak-core/latest/org/keycloak/representations/idm/UserRepresentation.html):

```
CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
credential.setValue("1234");

UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setUsername("test");
user.setFirstName("test");
user.setLastName("test");
user.setEmail("test@gmail.com");
user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
user.setEnabled(true);
user.setRealmRoles(Arrays.asList("admin"));

keycloak.realm("test-realm").users().create(user);
```

5. To create a new Group use [`GroupRepresentation`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.keycloak/keycloak-core/latest/org/keycloak/representations/idm/GroupRepresentation.html):

```
GroupRepresentation groupRepresentation = new GroupRepresentation()
groupRepresentation.setName("group");

Response response = keycloak.realm("test-realm").groups().add(groupRepresentation);
```

Note that when creating new top level group you should not pass group id - you can retrieve it after the group is created.

Answer (score 1):

```
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder() 
            .serverUrl("https://localhost:8443/auth")
            .realm("master")
            .username("admin") 
            .password("admin") 
            .clientId("Mycli") 
            .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()) 
            .build();

    CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
    credential.setValue("test123");

    UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
    user.setUsername("testuser2");
    user.setFirstName("Test2");
    user.setLastName("User2");
    user.setEmail("aaa@bbb.com");
    user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
    user.setEnabled(true);
    user.setRealmRoles(Arrays.asList("admin"));

    // Create testuser
    Response result = kc.realm("my-realem").users().create(user);
    if (result.getStatus() != 201) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't create user.");
        System.exit(0);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Testuser created.... verify in keycloak!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Keycloak Java adapters](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#java-adapters) are focused in usage rather than configuration. You'll need to implement yourself making the necessary calls with the required parameters. There's one tool for that kind of thins, the [admin-cli](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#the-admin-cli), but I think it won't be useful for your case.